# Way to get HTML5 AppCache 'file content' programmatically, in a hybrid mobile app?

Tags: html, caching

I have a hybrid mobile application based on HTML 5.. This app caches a few javascript resources in the HTML 5 AppCache. So, when the app is offline, it loads the cached js and runs well ... Now, is there a way by which the application's code (preferably through ObjC or Java, else, through jS) can access the contents of the javaScript resources in its AppCache, when the application is offline?

Based on responce from @robertc, following is the code i implemented

```
            $.ajax({
                url:"/abcweb/js/abc.scripts.min.js",
                dataType: "script",
                success: function(data){ 
                alert(data);
                }   
            });
```

I have changed the URL :P in this sample, .. but anyways, this works well, fetches the js content, when the application is online.. but when the app is offline, doesn't do the trick.. The same happens when i give the full URL..

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the same way it would access the contents of the resources if they weren't in the AppCache: request the URL with Ajax.  You should of course take care to structure your resources in such a way that they are usable from JavaScript, eg. avoid binary encoded blobs unless they are in a format a browser can already deal with (like PNG).

Comment: i tried what you mentioned.. with ajax, I'm able to get the .js file contents when the app is online.. but when i do the same offline, it doesn't seem to work.. any suggestions?

Comment: PS: I'm able to access LocalStorage content when the app is offline.. The app seems to even loads the scripts from the appCache when offline..

Comment: @ocelot Is the JS file in the AppCache?

Comment: @ocelot  Well it should work.  You'll need to add more details to your question.

Comment: @ocelot Add the code you're using to attempt to load the JS resources